# How do I rearrange this matrix equation to find X?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Given that the matrices $D$, $E$ and $F$ are invertible, how do I rearrange the equation to solve for $X$ when $D(X+3I)E = 5D(F+E) +E^2$.

Would I just take the inverse of $D$ and $E$ to both sides leaving me with $X= 5D(F+E)D^{-1}E^{-1} +EI - 3I $?

Comment: I reformatted the formulas. See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Just need to be careful since matrix multiplication is not generally commutative, i.e. it is not always the case that $AB=BA$. You have the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you multiply on the left by $D^{-1}$ on the left side, it should be on the left on the right side as well.  Then $D^{-1}5D=5$ and there shouldn't be any $D$s in the answer.  You have commuted the $(F+E)$ and the $D^{-1}$

Comment: That is essentially what I did though? I just multiplied the left hand side by D^-1 and E^-1 then subtracted the 3I.

Comment: I corrected the answer.